# How to terminate/close/quit correctly a thread when closing the gui thread in Qt

Tags: multithreading, qt, qtimer

Referring to the solution code reported here

[How to run a timer inside a QThread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958436/how-to-run-a-timer-inside-a-qthread)

it is not mentioned if one could encounter sigsev error in case the main (gui) thread is closed (with the X button for example).

My question is how should i handle (if should i handle it in first place) the termination of the second thread in case the GUI thread is terminated?

In case the data/events are not anymore relevant once the GUI termination has been issued can i just

```
m_thread->terminate();
```

in the MainWindow destructor or in the overridden CloseEvent()??

In case the data/events are relevant instead?

Comment: Unless absolutely forced to do so, avoid trying to explicitly terminate threads in user code, especially GUI user code.  Try very hard indeed to not design apps that need explicit thread termination.  Never, never, set any sort of 'terminate' flag and then wait in a GUI 'OnClose' event-handler, form destructor or similar, with join() or loop or any other kind of wait.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exit QThread when GUI Application exits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41411746/exit-qthread-when-gui-application-exits)

Comment: See also the Qt documentation of [QThread::terminate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#terminate) and [QThread](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details) itself. A clear example is provided.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is how should I handle (if should I handle it in first
>   place) the termination of the second thread in case the GUI thread is
>   terminated?

If the GUI thread is terminated we generally have the app quit the process? Let's say "GUI thread terminating" or maybe better "exiting" or "quitting" meaning already quit the GUI event loop so that no more interaction with worker threads from GUI thread. We still may have to explicitly release certain resources managed by the worker threads or otherwise we can potentially have the process stuck while quitting waiting on their release.